# PHP `virtual()` with Apache MultiViews not working after upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apache-2.2, php5

I use PHP's `virtual()` directive quite a lot on one of my sites, including central elements. This worked fine for the last ~10 years -- but after upgrading (or rather moving, as it is on a new machine) to Ubuntu 12.04 it somehow got broken.

#### Example setup (simplified)

To make it easier to understand, I simplify some things (contents). So say I need a HTML fragment like `<P>For further instructions, please look <A HREF='foobar'>here</P>` in multiple pages. 10 years ago, I used SSI for that, so it is put into a file in a central place -- so if e.g. the targeted URL changes, I only need to update it in one place. To serve multiple languages, I have Apache's `MultiViews` enabled -- and at `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/central/` there are the files:

- `foobar.html` (English variant, and the default)
- `foobar.html.de` (German variant).

Now in the PHP code, I simply placed:

`<? virtual("/central/foobar"); ?>`

and let Apache take care to deliver the correct language variant.

#### The problem

As said, this worked fine for about 10 years: German visitors got the German variant, all others the English (depending on their preferred language). But after upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04, it no longer worked: Either nothing was delivered from the `virtual()` command, or (in connection with framesets) it even ended up in binary gibberish.

Trying to figure out what happens, I played with a lot of things. I first thought `MultiViews` was (somehow) not available anymore -- but calling `http://<server>/central/foobar` showed the right variant, depending on the configured language preferences. This also proved there was nothing wrong with file permissions. The `error.log` gave no clues either (no error message thrown).

Finally, just as a "last ressort", I changed the PHP command to `<? virtual("central/foobar.html"); ?>` -- and that very same file was in fact included. So PHP's `virtual()` function basically worked -- but the language dependend stuff obviously did no longer work together with it as it did before.

As the "binary gibberish" mentioned above made me curious, I copy-pasted it into a file named `foo.gz`, and ran `gzip -d foo.gz`. As already suspected, this yielded no error message (though the output still was gibberish -- just different gibberish). Comparing the `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` on my new machine with a similar setup on an older machine turned up `mod_deflate` being enabled on the new machine. So I removed that from the enabled mods (by simply deleting the symbolic links), reloaded Apache... problem seemed solved: PHP's `virtual` now included the correct language variant. But Firefox now refuses to display the framesets (if the `virtual()` call was in the alternative part), but simply behaves as if no longer supporting them -- though they show up fine in the source (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> -- but having the included "virtual" file's content moved in front of the `<HEAD>` tag!). Trying again with the full file name in `virtual("central/foobar.html")` the frameset was interpreted correctly again (and the included content is in the correct place).

I'm totally confused now.

Of course I tried to find some change, using Google a lot, and also searching the questions here -- unfortunately to no avail.

#### Finally: The question

Putting "design questions" aside (surely today I would design things differently -- but at least currently I miss the time to change that for a quite huge amount of pages): **What can be done to make it work again?** I surely missed something -- but I cannot figure out what...

Comment: As this question mixes multiple problems, from which one I could meanwhile solve ("binary gibberish" due to `mod_deflate`), and to make the issue clearer, I placed the remaining problem as separate question: [apache2 - Strange behaviour of PHP's virtual() when Apache's mod_negotiation comes into play](http://serverfault.com/questions/448098/). Sorry for the mess...

Answer (score 1):

```
I believe your problem to be the apache configuration.

Troubleshooting tips:
  - check if mod_negotiation is loaded 
  - check that Multiview Option is enabled 
  - The default is to map headers like the language to something known by mod_mime, so check you have stuff like:
    AddLanguage de .de
    AddLanguage en .en
  - check what your browser is sending in the headers. Try duplicating it with curl

Alternatives:
  - Use mod_rewrite to rewrite the URL to the correct file and the virtual calls should work.
  - Try configuring the mime map manually:
    AddHandler type-map var
    Create a file named foobar.var with the following content:
    URI: foobar.html
    Content-Type: text/html
    Content-Language: en

    URI: foobar.html.de
    Content-Type: text/html
    Content-Language: de

    Check what happens when you access the foobar.var file.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Maybe I mixed too many elements into my question: Negotiation itself works fine, as described above. PHP's `virtual()` also works, if the *complete* filename is given. But if `virtual()` get's passed something which needs negotiation, the resulting content is always placed at the very top of the output (i.e. before the `<HTML>` element), regardless of the position of the `virtual()` call. Everything else I solved 10 minutes after the post (and updated the post then to reflect this, which might look a bit confusing). Maybe I should place that in a new question...