# Strange behaviour of PHP's virtual() when Apache's mod_negotiation comes into play

Tags: apache-2.2, php5

First: if acting separately, PHP's `virtual()` as well as Apache's `mod_negotiation` work fine. But I've got trouble when `virtual()` refers to a file which needs negotiation (e.g. Multi-Lang). Easiest explained using a simplified example:

In `/texts/` I place two files: `example.html` (Content: `<P>This is English</P>`) and `example.html.de` (`<P>Dies ist Deutsch</P>`). Now let's take an example PHP script:

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Example</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<? virtual("/texts/example.html"); ?>
</BODY></HTML>
```

This works fine, and the output is as expected:

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Example</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<P>This is English</P>
</BODY></HTML>
```

But now I change the `virtual()` call to `virtual("/texts/example");`, with my prefered language set to German. While negotiation picks the correct target, output is messed up:

```
<P>Dies ist Deutsch</P>
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Example</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Again: The only thing changed in above code was the parameter to the `virtual()` call. And those files were doing fine for about 10 years on my other machines -- just on my new one this crazy stuff started:

PHP version: 5.3.10 (on the working machine: 5.2.4)
Apache2 version: 2.2.22 (on the working machine: 2.2.8)

Any idea what could go wrong here?